# Arrange windows after change resolution

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm faced with the problem of moving\mixing\shuffling windows, after changing the screen resolution.

I change resolution from 1920x1080 (3 monitors) to 5760x1080 (eyefinity).

I could write a script for the correct placement of the windows. (Python + winapi)

But perhaps there is a program\script which can memorize (for different resolutions) the location of windows?

Comment: How many windows you have open when you need script to move them?

Comment: 15-25 and wanted to remember the location of 50-100

Comment: +1 because I sure hope someone answers this.  I use a laptop and a docking station, so my res changes twice a day.  Windows is absolutely pathetic about not being able to remember window/icon placements.  There are several apps out there that claim to do it, but none I've tried was worth a damn.

Comment: I have exactly the same question, but since you're asking for a tool that already does this rather than how to program one, I feel this question belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

A program called Fences will allow you to setup areas for icon placement. It will remember where they were for each resolution. I haven't found anything for remembering window placement on resolution change yet though.

http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/